# Mouse events at three.js scene

Tags: three.js

[This](https://threejs.org/editor/) is an original three.js editor and you can see that using *orbitControls* does not trigger object (de)selection. Like, if one object is selected (we can see a yellow box around it and *transformControls* attached to it), then object selection is not toggled on *mouseup* or *mousedown*. But then again, when we just need to choose an object - we just click on it and it's selected.

My problem is that in my editor a long click is considered to be a click as well. So when I finish rotating orbitControls, *mousedown* event happens and if some object was under the cursor, then this object gets (de)selected.

I want to know how to prevent this from happening. How to make it so that click is a click (for selecting an object) and long click is a long click (for controlling *orbitControls*)

Comment: Please keep in mind that the editor does not use `OrbitControls` but `EditorControls`. It's a early fork of `OrbitControls` and hence the implementations have diverged over the years.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.  If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Comment: Just create a boolean variable. When long-click is triggered, make `disabled = true`, and when click is triggered, check `if(disabled === true) {return}` otherwise go back to the initial state `disabled = false`